# Visual Studio 2019 installer Error "The source layout directory is too long"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I made an offline installer of the VS Community 2019. When running from that location the installer reports the following error:

> The source layout directory is too long. The layout directory name must be less than {0} characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows OS has this restriction that your path cannot be greater than a certain number. Install it in a simpler drive level directories like
"C:\Program Files\Visual Studio" or "C:\Visual Studio". More hierarchy adds to your limit and VS installation itself creates numerous inner level directories and at some point, some of those might hit the limit.

Answer (score 2):

this happens when the path is too long:
Fix:
*copy the setup directory to C:>*
rename the folder containing the setup files to a short name
like  *VS*

That should work

Answer (score 1):

Rename the installation file folder
For example VS2022

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31306657)

Answer (score 0):

easily, just rename the sub folder to the shorter. follow the video in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAcHEtvQpkY)